# Why is this find_package failing in newer CMake versions?

Tags: cmake, mpi, cmake-modules

I am experiencing a problem in a project, when upgrading from CMake 3.8 to 3.14. I have reduced this to the following issue. Note that `project` is before `find_package` (the other way around I do not have the issue I am describing).

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.1)
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
project(Test CXX)).
```

When I build with CMake 3.8, the output is as follows:

```
build3_8$ cmake ../source/
-- The CXX compiler identification is Intel 17.0.5.20170817
-- Check for working CXX compiler: (...)/linux/bin/intel64/icpc
-- Check for working CXX compiler: (...)/linux/bin/intel64/icpc -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: (...)/build3_8
```

With CMake 3.14 I get the following output:

```
build3_14$ cmake ../source/
CMake Error at (...)/CMake/3.14.0/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:211 (message):
  No REQUIRED_VARS specified for FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  (...)/CMake/3.14.0/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1672 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I wonder why this is happening with the newer CMake version (although FindMPI.cmake is completely different)?

Also, what can I do to solve this? Do I need to write my own config?

(I cannot just change the order of `project` and `find_package`, because wrappers are created for the compilers (not my choice, please don't blame me))

Comment: `FindMPI.cmake` script looks for MPI support only for languages which are used in the project. That is why it is crucial to have `find_package(MPI)` **after** the `project()` call. In CMake 3.8 the script detects needed languages by checking `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_WORKS` variable, in CMake 3.14 the variable `CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_LOADED` is checked instead. Probably, this is a reason of changed behavior you observe.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your comment. Can you consider posting it as an answer? It seems to answer the major question